# Getting row number of a cell in respect to a specified range

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to get the row number of a cell in a range that I specify with vba. I want to get the row number of the cell in the range but what I am getting is the row number of the cell in the worksheet.

This is the vba code I am using currently. I have set a range and within the range I search for a cell that contains the text string "C". Once I have found the cell I want to make changes to the value in the second column of the range.

```
Sub trial2()

Dim ActiveWB As Workbook
Dim ActiveWS As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range, findCell As Range

Set ActiveWB = ActiveWorkbook
Set ActiveWS = ActiveWB.ActiveSheet

Set rng = ActiveWS.Range("B4", "C10")

With rng
    Set findCell = .Cells.Find(what:="C")
End With

rng.Cells(findCell.Row, 2).Value = "change to something."

End Sub
```

Before running the code:

[image]

After running the code:

[image]

the cell value that contains "C" is in the 6th row of the worksheet, but in the 3rd row of the range. I was wondering how do I get the 3rd row of the range. I am aware that I can just offset the cell by 1 column to solve this problem, but I am curious about getting row numbers of cells in respect to a defined range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to adjust based on the number of the first row of `rng`, using simple math.

```
rng.Cells(findCell.Row - rng.Row + 1, 2).Value = "change to something."
```

In this case `6 - 4 + 1` = `3`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim rng As Range

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        'If your searching area for A,B,C etc is from B4 to B10 just use
        Set rng = .Range("B4:B10").Cells.Find(what:="C")
        'If your searching area for A,B,C etc is from B4 to C10 just use
        Set rng = .Range("B4:C10").Cells.Find(what:="C")

        If Not rng Is Nothing Then
            'Way 1
            .Cells(rng.Row, rng.Column + 1).Value = "change to something."
            'Way 2
            rng.Offset(0, 1).Value = "change to something."
        Else
            MsgBox "No ""C"" found."
        End If

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Instead of `.Cells(rng.Row, rng.Column + 1).Value` just `rng.Offset(0, 1).Value` and you must check `If Not rng Is Nothing` after find otherwise it will fail if nothing is found.

Comment: Isn't this way taking the "whole" worksheet(used cells in the worksheet) as the range and not the defined range?

Comment: Yes use every used cell. Which range you want to use? with Set rng = ActiveWS.Range("B4", "C10") you indicate that you will use only this to Cells and not from B4 to C10.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ Yes, I did realize I could do it using offset as I mentioned in the question. Out of curiosity, I wanted to know if vba had a way to get the row number of a cell from a defined range.

Comment: @DSM see edited answer and hope my notes help you to understand.